# How do you perform the hilbert transform using eigen?

Tags: c++, signal-processing, eigen

I've tried the following bit of code:

```
Eigen::MatrixXcd hilbert(const Parameters& p, const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXd>& bfFrame) {
    
    Eigen::FFT< double > fft;
    Eigen::MatrixXcd out(p.szZ,p.szX);
    
//     #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int k = 0; k < p.szX; k++) {
        Eigen::VectorXcd tmpOut = fft.fwd(bfFrame.col(k));
        tmpOut(Eigen::seq(0,p.szZ/2 - 1)).array() *= 0;
        tmpOut(p.szZ/2) *= 0.5;
        out.col(k) = fft.inv(tmpOut);
    }
    
    return out;
    
}
```

The above function yields a compile time error:

```
error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
         fwd( &dst[0],&src[0],nfft );
```

As I understand it, this means the template (or temporary, I might not have the correct terminology here) that is stored in tmpOut cant be passed as the parameter for fft.inv(). This feels like a basic fix, but I seem to be missing something....

Comment: Can you show more info from compiler output ?

Comment: I can verify the issue on my system. The FFT module isn't the most well-maintained. I recommend you switch to FFTW or MKL. This will also allow internal parallelization without you having to fiddle with OpenMP yourself.

Comment: This should work: `fft.fwd(VectorXd{bfFrame.col(k)});` (it does add a tiny bit of overhead, so maybe worth filing a bug report for that).

Comment: N.B.: What is the point of that `.array() *= 0` construct? Just use `.setZero()` (unless you really want special behavior for NaN or Inf values).

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to fix the compile time error! Maybe this should be a separate question, but why exactly does it break as currently written? 

Also, there's no good reason I'm doing `.array() *= 0`. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The reason it breaks with `fft.fwd(bfFrame.col(k))` is that inside the FFT module someone calls `&src[0]` instead of `&src.coeffRef(0)`. And constant column-expressions appear to have `operator[]` return by value.